# merge two different images in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, merge, uiimage

I want to merge two `UIImage` in Swift:

[image]

and

[image]

I tried it with

```
func maskImage(image: UIImage, withMask maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let maskRef = maskImage.CGImage

    let mask = CGImageMaskCreate(
        CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
        nil,
        false)

    let masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, mask)
    let maskedImage = UIImage(CGImage: masked!)

    // No need to release. Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed.

    return maskedImage

}
```

and the  call

```
    let imageName = data.valueForKey("imagename")!.description
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageBackground : UIImage = UIImage(named:"background")!    
    let maskedImage: UIImage = self.maskImage(image!, withMask: imageBackground)

    cell.imageButton.setImage(maskedImage, forState: .Normal)
```

the result is just the image that i get with **`let image = UIImage(named: imageName)`**, the second image (volleyball)

What´s my error?

Comment: What does "merge" mean? What do you want the result to look like? If you want to combine the two images, why don't you just draw the two images into a single image context?

Comment: with merge i mean that both images are added in to one image (volleball with a grav triangle on bottom-left)! Ok?

Comment: i don´t draw it in one context, cause in one view i need "volleyball" **without** the triangle and in another view **with** the triangle. And this 
affects to about 20 images. I want to save resources...

Comment: i really don´t know, why i´m voted down. :-(

Comment: "i don´t draw it in one context, cause in one view i need "volleyball" without the triangle and in another view with the triangle" That objection makes no sense at all.

Comment: I look your code, it think it's correct, you must simply invert images to obtain what do you want...

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano have a look at your very welciome anwer :-)

Comment: @matt sorry, that must be my terrible english.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't care about performance you can use `Core Image`

```
let volleyballImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named:"volleyball.png")!)
let otherImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named:"other.png")!)
let compositeFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")!

compositeFilter.setValue(volleyballImage,
                         forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
compositeFilter.setValue(otherImage,
                         forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

if let compositeImage = compositeFilter.outputImage{
    let image = UIImage(CIImage: compositeImage)
    // do something with the "merged" image
}
```

Comment: Thanks beywulf that´s it!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in few lines:

```
var bottomImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")!
var topImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"background")!
// Change here the new image size if you want
var newSize = CGSizeMake(bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, bottomImage.scale)
bottomImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height))
topImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height), blendMode:CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha:1.0)
var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Never call UIGraphicsBeginImageContext; call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. And never call either of them without calling UIGraphicsEndImageContext.

Comment: Thank you matt , I dont knew it.  Ok now it will be correct! UIGraphicsBeginImageContext take the size, but dont care about opaque and scale, ..options seems more right..

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano that´s it almost. All is right, but the "volleyball" looks like a negative of a photo.. I would like to add a screenshow, but i don´t know how...

Comment: Right perhaps it depend by the opaque parameters, try to set  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions with opaque in false

Answer (score 1):

You can use my simple method to merge two images in half.
Like this:
[image]

```swift
  func mergeTwoImage(leftImg:UIImage,rightImg:UIImage) -> UIImage?{
        
        let size = CGSize(width: leftImg.size.width, height: leftImg.size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        
        let area1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        let area2 = CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        
        
        leftImg.draw(in: area1)
        rightImg.draw(in: area2, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return finalImage
    }
```